# iOS - connect to server via singleton implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, singleton, restkit

I have json file in the server with rest APLI, I want to communicate with server, right now I connect to the server with this method and call it in my viewdidload method, my question is , what is the best way to do this, can I use singleton? if yes how it should looks like? Thanks in advance!

Appreciate any code suggestion in answer section.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
 _mapView.delegate = self;
    [self fetchData];
}



 -(void)fetchData
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASED_URL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[GETReply bytes] length:[GETReply 
length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];


CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         
NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    // handle the error 
}

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{

    location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    // create the annotation
    MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;


    newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];

    newAnnotation.coordinate = location;

    [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
}
[self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
}
```

**UPDATE: Based on the comments Singleton is not necessary to do network functions and its not advisable to do.**

How can I improve these code, Appreciated if you can give me solution for improving the code

Comment: `Singleton` is used to create a single instance through out the app. In case of Network activities, it is not advised to use Singleton as you may need to create multiple network connections at one time, it will not work. You might choose static functions instead, and some good libraries like `AFNetworking` to reduce your code.

Comment: @iphonic Thank you for your comment, would you please give me an example how can I improve my code?(please give an example based on my code) I appreciated if you write it in answer part, then the other people also can use it, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my comment.

`Singleton` is used to create a single instance through out the app. In case of Network activities, it is not advised to use Singleton as you may need to create multiple network connections at one time, it will not work. You might choose static functions instead, and some good libraries like `AFNetworking` to reduce your code. And too you should use `asynchronous` network activity rather than `synchronous` because it will `block app activity` if it take time to fetch data.

To modify your code you can follow the following code.

Create an `ApiManager` class that will do all the network activities, put all you code in the class.. See below

**`ApiManager.h`**

## import

```
@interface ApiManager : NSObject
+(void)fetchCoordinates:(void (^) (id result))success failure:(void (^) (NSError *error))failure;
@end
```

**`ApiManager.m`**

```
#import "ApiManager.h"

#define BASED_URL @""


@implementation ApiManager
+(void)fetchCoordinates:(void (^) (id result))success failure:(void (^) (NSError *error))failure{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASED_URL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *GETReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];

    if(!error){
        success(array);
    }else
        failure(error);

}
@end
```

**`Usage`**

```
[ApiManager fetchCoordinates:^(id result) {

     NSArray *array=(NSArray*)result;

     NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 

     for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
     {

     location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
     location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

     // create the annotation
     MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;


     newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
     newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];

     newAnnotation.coordinate = location;

     [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
 }
 [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much, where should I add this part ? for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{

    location.latitude = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [dictionary[@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    // create the annotation
    MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;


    newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.company = dictionary[@"company"];

Answer (score 0):

- Singleton is not necessary to do network functions and its not advisable to do.
- You may need to do multithreading when calling network APIs
- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a good library to look into and make use of your friend for network related codes. Its under active development, have a good community of users as well.

Comment: Change your second point to: "Your customers will hate you with a vengeance if you don't use multithreading when calling network APIs".

Comment: What I am confused about is that the `AFNetworking` docs actually recommend to use a singleton: "Developers targeting iOS 7 or Mac OS X 10.9 or later that deal extensively with a web service are encouraged to subclass `AFHTTPSessionManager`, providing a class method that returns a shared singleton object on which authentication and other configuration can be shared across the application." (see here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html).  Would this be the exception that defines the rule ?

Comment: And even Apple uses a Singleton for a Network manager class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MVCNetworking/Listings/Networking_NetworkManager_h.html